# Comparing polygons in two layers based on their location in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection, overlapping-features

I'm trying to compare two layers representing the cycleways of my hometown. I've exported one layer from OpenStreetMap and the other from a regional web site.

Now I want to compare the two layer and if they intersect or are very near one another, I want to keep just the data from the regional website.

The data from OSM are lines while the other data are polygons, so I created a `buffer` around the OSM data and used the function `Intersection`. Then I used the function `Symmetrical difference` once with the buffer and the `intersection` (case1), then with the regional polygon and the `intersection` (case 2) but this doesn't work correctly.

As you can see in the picture the green polygon represents the `intersection`, the red one represents case 1 and the orange case 2. The problem is that all areas belong to the same attribute so in this case I want to keep just the green one.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use ["Clip"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#clip) instead of "Intersection".

[image]