# Comparing two different layers with duplicates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, intersection, query-layer, duplicates

I'm trying to compare *'layer A'* with *'layer B'*. Layer B is the result of the intersection between layer A and another layer C, so the elements in B are all contained in A. My goal is to create a new layer with only the attributes from (A-B), so a layer with the attributes that belong just to A and not B.

I've tried merging A and B and then used the "eliminate duplicates by attribute" function but this doesn't work since the output is still A.
Do you have any suggestion?

I have these two layers, the columns represent the features. As you can see, all the features of layer B also belong to A. I want to create another layer with only the features with id=3,5,7, so the features that belong to A but not to B.

```
id Features A  | id Features B

     1            1

     2            2

     3            

     4            4

     5            

     6            6

     7
```

Comment: Welcome, new user anea! Do you mean *features* both where you write *elements* and *attributes* above? And is there a single attribute that uniquely identifies a feature in both A and B, so can compare features in A and B just examining that one attribute? It could be an autogenerated "FID" or a manually entered name attribute that identifies each feature uniquely.

Comment: I think a visual example would be a great help in understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Houska Hi! yes I mean features and yes there are many attributes that uniquely identifies a feature in both A and B. My main problem is that the geometry of A and B doesn't match. As you can see In the picture I added, the orange area is A, the green area is B so if a use the tool "difference" the output still contains the orange area that doesn't overlap. I wanted to work on the attributes since they are the same both in A and in B. I'm adding a picture of the two attributes table right now.

Comment: and what is it you utlimately wish to compare, the overlap between A and C? If you refer to my [answer of your previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/421809/128665), `Clip` can be used to get only the intersecting part.

Comment: @Matt my wish is to create a new layer A with the features that belong only to A. By this I mean that I want to delete all the features from A that are in C (which are all in A, since C is the result of the intersection between A and B).

Comment: Sorry, I am having a really hard time understanding what you mean. I think judging by the fact the question has had 25 views and no answer, I am not the only one. 

I think you need to rephrase your question much more clearly, with perhaps a sketch of what you expect to end up with. All the talk of As and Bs and Cs and now a new A is pretty confusing.

Comment: @matt I tried to explain it in a different way. English is not my first language so please, understand my struggle.

Comment: Your new explanation is much clearer, thank you :) See my answer for a possible method using the `Extract by expression` tool.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use the "Difference" tool, with the input layer as A, and the Overlay layer as B? This should give you the part of A that is not in B, with only the attributes that were in the original layer A.

Alternatively, you could use the Difference tool with Input as A and Overlay as C and you should get a polygon that has the part of A not in C, with only the attributes in A. This will mean you don't have to generate layer B, saving space if the layer is particularly large.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: Check @DoubleD's answer first, because I also have the feeling you can skip this whole duplicate problem with a slightly different approach to intersecting your layers.*

But here is a solution to your current question:

This expression gets all the feature IDs (`$id`) from `layer B` where the field `id Features B` is `NULL` (no value). It could be any field, you can change the name as you wish.

It creates an `array` from those `$id`'s. Then checks each feature in `layer A` to see if its `$id` is in the `array`. If it is (which means there is no attribute value for `layer B`) then the feature from `layer A` is extracted.

The last line is to check that there is also a value in the `id Features B` field.

```sql
array_contains(
    aggregate(layer:= 'layer B',          
              aggregate:= 'array_agg',   
              expression:= $id, 
              filter:= "id Features B" IS NULL), $id
    ) 
              
AND "id Features A" IS NOT NULL
```

Use the expression with the `Extract by expression` tool on `layer A`.

[image]

The result is a new layer with features from `layer A` where the `id Features B` field in `layer B` is `NULL`

[image]

Don't forget to change the layer name and field names in the expression to what you are using in your project.

*I am not 100% sure using the `$id` of `layer B` to check against will work with your data, but let me know if it does not and I will fix it*